# how to remove a block from backend? Magento

Tags: magento, block

I want to disable search box in some CMS pages and categories, I read that it is possible to do it from backend (using xml update), how can I do this? So far I think it is like:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>NAME_OF_BLOCK</name></action>
</reference>
```

Please let me know:

a) how do I get the name of the block that I want to remove?

b) how do I get the name of the reference ? (content in my example)

c) Do I have just to write down that code in "Custom Layout Update XML" textedit box?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After finding out the block name (by using steps described in this link: 
http://gordonlesti.com/how-to-find-the-name-in-layout-of-a-block-in-magento/

I was able to do:

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.search"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

based on:
[Why doesn't this work: <remove name="header.top.search"/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696072/why-doesnt-this-work-remove-name-header-top-search)

Hope this will help someone.